# A problem with Gstreamer 1.0 on ROS

Tags: ros, video, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to get running a UDP Camera with the help of Gstreamer on ROS.

I carefully went through the tutorials of Gstreamer and I managed to get a functional C program to get the video feed. I mean, I know the pipeline is correct. I built this program with cmake and make, it works with gstreamer 1.0 and it depays/decodes RTP H264 video. When I run this program I can confirm with: `gst_version_string()` that the version of Gstreamer is >1.0.

The problem arises when I try to do this on ROS. I added the exact same lines on the cmakeslists.txt of my package to find and link Gstreamer 1.0, but when I run my node I get gstreamer version is 0.10. The lines that share my cmakelists.txt  on the pure C and Ros Package are:

```
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GSTREAMER REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0)
pkg_check_modules(GST_APP REQUIRED gstreamer-app-1.0)
```

So, my best guess is that I have to change something on my cmakeslist.txt or some catkin_make related setting. Do you know how can I make this work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

DSG

ps. I require Gstreamer 1.0 because 0.1 is now not recommended. Ubuntu recently moved to libav which works great with 1.0 and lastly, the components on the pipeline I'm using to decode H264 are only available on 1.0.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233272/a-problem-with-gstreamer-1.0-on-ros/) by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2016-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabiobreo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27237/fabiobreo/) on 2016-06-23**:
Did you solve it? If so, can you share your solution?

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2018-04-24**:
Same here: Sharing is caring :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes sir, I did!

```
## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
## GStreamer 1.0 package required
find_package(PkgConfig)

macro(find_gstreamer_component prefix pkg lib)
  pkg_check_modules(PC_${prefix} REQUIRED ${pkg})
  find_library(${prefix}_LIBRARIES NAMES ${lib} HINTS ${PC_${prefix}_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PC_${prefix}_LIBDIR})
  list(APPEND gstreamer_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PC_${prefix}_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  list(APPEND gstreamer_LIBRARIES ${${prefix}_LIBRARIES})
  mark_as_advanced(${prefix}_LIBRARIES gstreamer_LIBRARIES gstreamer_INCLUDE_DIRS)
endmacro()

find_gstreamer_component(gst      gstreamer-1.0       gstreamer-1.0)
find_gstreamer_component(gstbase  gstreamer-base-1.0  gstbase-1.0)
find_gstreamer_component(gstapp   gstreamer-app-1.0   gstapp-1.0)
find_gstreamer_component(gstvideo gstreamer-video-1.0 gstvideo-1.0)
```

I'm terribly sorry not to give credit to the authors, but I don't remember where I find a ROS package that also required Gstreamer 1.0.

cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Nexus8](https://answers.ros.org/users/26736/nexus8/) with karma: 106 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fabiobreo](https://answers.ros.org/users/27237/fabiobreo/) on 2016-06-27**:
Thanks a lot, it worked for me!